# JSON Object property setting in Logic Apps workflows

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

Basically, I am creating a complex JSON Object variable, two of them actually. One to form the body of an HTTP response to the calling app and another to by the body of a POST to an API. The complex JSON object has boolean properties, arrays, and nested object. I have a lot of property setting to do. What I am finding is that I have to do a Compose action on the current state of the object, then do a Set Variable action to set the variable to the output of the Compose action. Basically, two actions for each and every property update. Am I missing something? Is it possible to set the property on a JSON object with only one Action and not two?

Here is the code of a simple Logic App showing the two step process of two Actions to update a single property:

```
{
"definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
        "Check_Compose_result_shows_array_is_still_empty": {
            "inputs": {
                "name": "temp",
                "value": "@{first(variables('JsonObj').apiUrls)}"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Compose_into_an_array": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "SetVariable"
        },
        "Check_that_bool_property_was_changed": {
            "inputs": {
                "name": "temp",
                "value": "@{variables('JsonObj').success}"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Set_variable": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "SetVariable"
        },
        "Compose_into_an_array": {
            "inputs": "@setProperty(variables('JsonObj'),'apiUrls',union(variables('JsonObj').apiUrls,json('[''http//:apiBaseUrl/EDI/containers/defaults'']')))",
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_JSON_Object_variable": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Compose"
        },
        "Compose_to_set_bool_property": {
            "inputs": "@setProperty(variables('JsonObj'),'success',true)",
            "runAfter": {
                "Set_variable_to_retain_Compose_output": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Compose"
        },
        "Initialize_JSON_Object_variable": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "JsonObj",
                        "type": "Object",
                        "value": "@json(concat('{ ''success'': false, ''apiUrls'': [], ''workFlow'': ',workflow(),'}'))"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_temp_variable_": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Initialize_temp_variable_": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "temp",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Set_variable": {
            "inputs": {
                "name": "JsonObj",
                "value": "@outputs('Compose_to_set_bool_property')"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Compose_to_set_bool_property": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "SetVariable"
        },
        "Set_variable_to_retain_Compose_output": {
            "inputs": {
                "name": "JsonObj",
                "value": "@outputs('Compose_into_an_array')"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Check_Compose_result_shows_array_is_still_empty": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "SetVariable"
        }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {},
    "triggers": {
        "manual": {
            "inputs": {
                "schema": {}
            },
            "kind": "Http",
            "type": "Request"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you don't use a Liquid Map?

Answer (score 0):

> One to form the body of an HTTP response to the calling app and another to by the body of a POST to an API....I have a lot of property setting to do.

Then you should be using **Transform** instead of Compose.

Since the content is already JSON, the most direct path would be [Liquid Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform).

However, if you're already versed in Xsl, that's an option also.

Comment: To be clear, maybe more clear than in my post, I have many sets of actions that are of the form: read a single property from the JSON, call an API op, update one property of the JSON. This last step of trio I have as many Compose-Set pairs of actions. You advise for updating a single property in a JSON object, Transform with Liquid Transform is the best practice?

Comment: 15 - 20 unique API calls. Each API is a "set" for me: setting up the RESTy URL (concats for path params from the JSON properties), handling the response, then updating a property or two in the JSON object based on the results. (This is somewhat simplified) I am processing ASNs....